# PHP storing data into a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I have an array where the 1st item is a key of a category, 2nd is a name of that category, 3rd item is a key of a subcategory, 4th its name, 5th a key of a subsubcategory... I'd like to store the data into a new array where the keys would carry the hierarchy. Therefor it would look like this:

```
$dat[$ar[1]] = $ar[2];
$dat[$ar[1]][$ar[3]] = $ar[4];
$dat[$ar[1]][$ar[3]][$ar[5]] = $ar[6];
$dat[$ar[1]][$ar[3]][$ar[5]][$ar[7]] = $ar[8];
etc.
```

The number of items of $ar and therefor the depth of $dat is fixed. How to write a for cycle to achieve the above described behavior?

Comment: Can you provide some example input data, and some expected output data?

Comment: Is your `$ar` a scalar array that is 0-based, instead of starting at 1?  Or an actual associative array?
Is it suppose to be like `$ar = array('color','blue','type','plant','flower','tulip')` or more like `$ar = array('1' => 'color', '2' => 'blue', '3' => 'blue', '4' => 'plant', '5' => 'plant', '6' => 'flower', '7' => 'flower', '8' => tulip')`

Comment: the array is a scalar array starting from index 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that exact request is possible.  Consider that `$dat[$ar[1]][$ar[3]] = $ar[4]` is the same as `$dat[$ar[1]] = array($ar[3] => $ar[4])`.  That means you are trying to assign `$dat[$ar[1]]` twice like this:

```
$dat[$ar[1]] = $ar[2];
$dat[$ar[1]] = array($ar[3] => $ar[4]);
```

which overwrites the first value and makes it pointless.  What maybe you really want is something like:

```
$dat[$ar[0]]['value'] = $ar[1];
$dat[$ar[0]][$ar[2]]['value'] = $ar[3];
$dat[$ar[0]][$ar[2]][$ar[4]]['value'] = $ar[5];
$dat[$ar[0]][$ar[2]][$ar[4]][$ar[6]]['value'] = $ar[7];
```

This also hopes that 'value' is never a value in your `$ar` array to be used as a key.  For simplicity, I am going to assume you are using a scalar array that is 0-based, like `$ar = array('color','blue','type','plant','flower','tulip')`  Then try this:

```
$dat = array();
$pnt = &$dat;
$cnt = count($ar);
for ($key=0; $key < $cnt; $key+=2) {
    $value = $ar[$key];
    $pnt[$value]['value'] = $ar[$key + 1];  // we assign it to the key 'value' of the current array dimension
    $pnt = &$pnt[$value]; // we now point to the new array dimension
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($dat);
echo '</pre>';
```

Then your output would be like:

```
Array
(
    [color] => Array
        (
            [value] => blue
            [type] => Array
                (
                    [value] => plant
                    [flower] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => tulip
                        )
                )
        )
)
```